# JS "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'" with Arrow function within object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

So, I'm trying to assign a arrow function to a variable within an object. Whenever I do this, it errors saying unexpected syntax. Are we not meant to assign arrow functions to variables within an object?

```
class contentController{
    constructor(tabs,tree){
        this.tree=tree;
        this.tabs=tabs;
        this.tabs.addCallback(id=>this.clickTab(id));
        this.tree.addCallback(id=>this.clickTree(id));
        this.currentId=null;
        this.currentTab=null;
        this.properties=document.getElementById('category_props');
        this.products=document.getElementById('category_items');
        this.propform=document.getElementById('categorypropform');
        this.events={
            clickReset:(e)=>{this->clickReset(e)}, //does not like!
            clickUpdate:(e)=>{this->clickUpdate(e)} //this either
        }
        this.events.clickUpdate=clickUpdate;
        this.events.clickReset(1);
    }

    //class continues for many, many lines...
}
```

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax.. Arrow functions look like `(args) => { }` and method access looks like: `this.clickReset(e)`

Comment: The error is not from your arrow function. It is from `this->clickUpdate(e)`. There is no `->` operator in JavaScript. That should be a `.`.

Comment: Omg, I was fixated on the arrow function, but didn't even notice the body of the function. That's what you get for coding php and javascript. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, you can make that more readable by declaring a method on the `events` object: `clickReset(e) { this.clickReset(e); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax error, in arrow function you would need to always use =>, and the way to access to a property of an element, such as method(functions) is with the dot notation

```
   class contentController{
        constructor(tabs,tree){
            this.tree=tree;
            this.tabs=tabs;
            this.tabs.addCallback(id=>this.clickTab(id));
            this.tree.addCallback(id=>this.clickTree(id));
            this.currentId=null;
            this.currentTab=null;
            this.properties=document.getElementById('category_props');
            this.products=document.getElementById('category_items');
            this.propform=document.getElementById('categorypropform');
            this.events={
                clickReset:(e)=>{this.clickReset(e)}, 
                clickUpdate:(e)=>{this.clickUpdate(e)} 
        }
            this.events.clickUpdate=clickUpdate;
            this.events.clickReset(1);
        }
        //class continues for many, many lines...
    }
```